# How to measure dimensions of a widget using Offstage?

Tags: flutter

[Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html) says:

> Offstage can be used to measure the dimensions of a widget without bringing it on screen (yet)

How can I measure the dimensions using `Offstage`?

Comment: Following the example in the docs, but using a different widget as a child, I always get Size(0, 0). Any idea why?

Comment: @VincentGagnon Sorry I didn't try that.